# Parameter types in type definition

Tags: haskell

I have a data type like so:

```
data MyType a b = Something a b | .....
```

and then I have a type:

```
type SomethingElse = MyType a b -> AnotherThing
```

However, if I include the a and b parameter for the type definition it complains, but if I leave them out it also complains.

The error message (in the type definition) is that variables a and b are not in scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you're not providing concrete types for `a` and `b`, you need to parametrize your type synonym over those as well.

```
type SomethingElse a b = MyType a b -> AnotherThing
```